# How to Determine the Number of Independent Tests When Considering Multiple Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, biostatistics, false-discovery-rate

I have a question regarding how to determine the number of independent tests when performing multiple testing corrections.

Suppose my research hypothesis is whether age is related to cognition decline in females, and I have four cognitive outcomes.

In my actual analysis, I tested the association between age and cognition (all four outcomes) in three separate subsample analyses: the full sample, females only, and males only. In this case, should I correct for multiple testing for all 12 tests (3 subsample analyses * four outcomes) or should I correct for multiple testing for only the four outcomes within each subsample analysis (e.g., 4 cognition tests in the female subsample analysis)?

I received conflicting answers when I tried to investigate this question from online sources. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me answer this question.